# $A^X$ has nilpotent element iff A does

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need to do the following exercise

> Let $A^{X}$ be the set of maps $f: X \rightarrow A$ where $X$ is a given set and $A$ is a given ring with the operations defined by $$(f+g)(a)=f(a)+g(a)$$$$(f g)(a)=f(a) g(b)$$ where the sum and the product in these expressions are taken in $A$.
> Prove that the ring $A^{X}$ has nilpotent elements if and only if $A$ does.

I have been trying to do it but I'm not sure if what I did is correct. 
This is what I've done:

We know an element is nilpotent if $x^n=0$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. That is, if $(f^n)(a)=0$. 
Using the defined operations we have $$(f^n)(a)=(f \cdots f)(a)=f(a)\cdots f(a)=\left(f(a)\right)^n$$
Therefore  $$(f^n)(a)=0 \Leftrightarrow \left(f(a)\right)^n=0$$
That is,  an element of $A^X$ is nilpotent if and only if it is nilpotent in A.

Is this correct? If not, how do I proceed?

Comment: I think you have the right general idea, but you're getting a little confused in your notation. It doesn't really make sense to say that an element in $A^X$ is nilpotent in $A$ if and only if it is nilpotent in $A$, since maps $X\to A$ are not elements of $A$. Instead think about proving this in either direction separately. Hint: if $a \in A$ is nilpotent, what do you know about the map sending every element in $X$ to $a$?

Comment: The correct claim is: Let $X$ be a non-empty set. Then $A^X$ has a non-zero nilpotent iff $A$ has a non-zero nilpotent. (Notice that this is wrong for the empty set, and also that $0$ is always nilpotent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note as Martin Brandenberg points out, you need to be a little attentive to the edge cases here, in particular by nilpotent in your question, we really want to say non-zero nilpotent, which are the interesting nilpotent elements anyway :), and we need to take $X \neq \emptyset$. Otherwise, this result is trivial since $0$ is nilpotent and in both of these rings.

If $A$ has some non-zero nilpotent element $a$, say $a^n = 0$, then the map $f\in A^X$ defined by mapping every element of $X$ to $a$ is nilpotent since
$$
(f^n)(x) = (f(x))^n = a^n = 0
$$
So $f^n$ is the zero map, hence non-zero nilpotent (note since $a\neq 0, f\neq 0$).

For the other direction fix some non-zero nilpotent $f \in A^X$ with $f^n = 0$. Since $f \neq 0$, there is some $f(x) = a \in \text{im}(f)\subseteq A$ with $a\neq 0$. Then we have that:
$$
a^n = (f(x))^n = f^n(x) = 0
$$
so $a$ is non-zero nilpotent, which proves the desired result.

Comment: Okay! Thank you!

Comment: See my comment above; I  think the answer has to be adjusted a bit accordingly.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg yes you are right, I didn't include that to avoid making this overly cumbersome.

Comment: "in particular by nilpotent here, I mean non-zero nilpotent, which are the interesting nilpotent elements anyway". I suggest to not change a standard definition. This makes many mathematical statements more clumsy to state. For example: the intersection of all prime ideals in a comm. ring is the set of nilpotents ... and $0$? No, $0$ is nilpotent already. And the sum of two nilpotents in a comm. ring is nilpotent ... or $0$? Well, $0$ is nilpotent already.

Comment: In your second paragraph, do you mean to define $f$ as mapping every element of $X$ to $\color{red}{a}$, not $A$? And in the following sentence, do you mean to say $f^n$ is the zero map?

Comment: @ElliotYu yes, thanks for catching that

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I take your point, and I've changed my answer in the interest of being as correct as possible. However, I don't totally agree with your characterization. I'm not saying that we should define nilpotent in a different, just that when thinking about problems like this \textit{in a colloquial context} we don't always need to be totally precise in our language.